# Are textfields not allowed in arrays in as3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, textfield, nullreferenceexception

I have an array

```
var skillMenuText:Array = new Array();
```

and I want to fill it with textfields that I will alter the text of later.

I tried declaring a textfield

```
var t:TextField = new TextField();
```

which didn't give me any problems, but as soon as I tried to add `t` to the array,

```
skillMenuText[0] = t;
```

it gave me a 1009 error:

```
Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Do I need imports or a different method of putting text-controls in an array?

Comment: They are allowed, and that should work. Could you add your exact code? Seems to be something different compared to what is showcased in this text

Comment: Most likely `trace(skillMenuText)` will show you a null.

Comment: @Vesper, yes the trace returns null. How do I fix that?

Comment: You should review your code flow so that your array is first initialized and then filled with whatever data you want.

Comment: Sounds more like a scope issue than an instantiation order issue to me. Make sure the `skillMenuText` array is actually available when you try to use it (i.e. make sure it isn't an object created in another function or class)

Comment: I had the initialization of the array before all of my functions, and the items initialized inside the function, but I just initialized everything inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I called the function that initialization the array, it hadn't completed initialization before the next function was called and the array was accessed, giving me the error. By waiting until later to access the array, I avoided the error.

Comment: Sounds like the function that initializes the array is called asynchronously.  Object instantiation/initialization is always started and finished in a single line of code, and with very rare exceptions, AS3 is single-threaded.

Comment: Yes, the function hadn't been accessed until the array was accessed and returned an error